# Set Repeating alarm starting at a time that has already passed. What happens now?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                startingTime, App.SYNC_DATA_FREQUENCY,
                dataSyncServicePendingIntent);
```

What happens if the `startingTime` has already passed. Will the alarm also fire for the previous times when it should've fired ?

Comment: Nope. It will trigger the next time it is scheduled for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alarm will be triggered immediately.

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) states:

```
 If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, 
 with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.
```

Comment: So, if I set a frequency of 1 minute and the starting time of the alarm is an hour past, it'll execute 60 times ?

Comment: NO. It'll execute NOW. Then it'll execute NOW + 1 minute, NOW + 2 minutes and so on.

Comment: Ignoring the number of times it should've executed ideally ?